# Error message Use of undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is the code above:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self showLoginProcess:false];

#ifdef DEBUG
self.usernameBox.text = @"passenger@test.com";
self.passwordBox.text = @"123456";
NSLog(@"baseUrl = %@", kBaseURL);
#endif

//TODO: check if internet is available




  (void)testInternetConnection
    {
        internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

        // Internet is reachable
        internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
        {
            // Update the UI on the main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"There is an internet connection");
            });
        };
```

> The first line -(void)testInternetConnection gives me an error message
>   which says: Use of undeclared identifier 'testInternetConnection'

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add this line: - (void)testInternetConnection; to .h file

Comment: Please post the code above that line; I believe the error is there.

Comment: you are declaring `-(void)testInternetConnection` inside viewDidLoad?

Comment: I am new to programming. So this is still a bit new to me

Answer (score 0):

Check brackets , semi colons above this method.

There is problem in line above this function. select this function and Cut

```
(CMD + X)
```

then check the error in above line.

Add  function in header (.h) file as  `- (void)testInternetConnection;`

Comment: Why have you converted our comments into an answer?  The question cannot be answered yet.

Comment: i had not seen any comment #Droppy. Just checked now.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing class type before the var.
Try adding:

Reachability* internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWit .... , as below

```
- (void)testInternetConnection
{
  Reachability* internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"There is an internet connection");
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)testInternetConnection
{
        internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

        // Internet is reachable
        internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
        {
            // Update the UI on the main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"There is an internet connection");
            });
        };
}  // You may be missed your closing bracket
```